# The controller for path was not found or does not implement IController in MVC

Tags: c#, .net, web, model-view-controller

I am facing a problem here with MVC.

I have a `_Layout.cshtml` file with the following code

```
@{Html.RenderAction("Menus", "Menu", new { ActiveMenuId = ViewBag.ActiveMenu });}
```

and the action called goes like this

```
[ChildActionOnly]
public ActionResult Menus(int ActiveMenuId)
{
    var model = GetMenus(context, ActiveMenuId);
    return PartialView("_Menu", model);
}
```

model will be containing the Menu details such as ControllerName, ActionName, etc.

The partial view is like this

```
@model IList<App.Models.Menu>
<div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarColor01">
<ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
    @{
        foreach (var m in Model)
        {
            <li class="@m.ActiveClass">
                @{
                    <a href="@Url.Action(m.ActionName, m.ControllerName, new { area = m.Area })" class="nav-link"><span class="fas @m.IconClass"></span>@m.DisplayName</a>
                }
            </li>
        }
    }
</ul>
```

When the `foreach` hits the data

```
Models.Menu
{
    ActionName: "Index",
    ControllerName: "Home",
    Area: "Area1",
    IconClass: "someClass",
    DisplayName: "Area1",
    ActiveClass: "someClass"
}
```

it generates a URL `/Area1`

Yet somehow, if I clicked that Area1 menu, it throws an error

```
The controller for path '/Area1' was not found or does not implement IController.
```

And the controller I'm calling inside the area was this one.

```
namespace App.Areas.Area1.Controllers
{
    public class HomeController : Controller
    {
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            ViewBag.Title = "Area1";
            return View();
        }
    }
}
```

Here is the `Area1AreaRegistration.cs`

```
namespace App.Areas.Area1
{
    public class Area1AreaRegistration : AreaRegistration 
    {
        public override string AreaName 
        {
            get 
            {
                return "Area1";
            }
        }

        public override void RegisterArea(AreaRegistrationContext context) 
        {
            context.MapRoute(
                name: "Area1_default",
                url: "Area1/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
                defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional },
                namespaces: new [] {"App.Areas.Area1.Controllers"}
            );
        }
    }
}
```

And here is my `RouteConfig.cs`

```
namespace App
{
    public class RouteConfig
    {
        public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
        {
            routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

            routes.MapRoute(
                name: "Default",
                url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
                defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional },
                namespaces: new[] { "App.Controllers" }
            );
        }
    }
}
```

Hope you guys can help me with this one.

Comment: Follow up on this issue. I recently found out that the reason for the error is with regards to layout. If i set the layout of the view returned by the controller inside the area to null, it works, but without the layout.

Comment: the example isn't exactly "minimal". Can you please shorten it down?